# Searching for a Specific String in multiple files and Copying all the files recursively

Tags: bash, scripting

I am having 35K + odd files in multiple directories and subdirectories. There are 1000 odd files (.c .h and other file names) with a unique string "FOO" in the **FILE CONTENT**. I am trying to copy those files alone (with the directory structure preserved) to a different directory 'MEOW'. Can some one look in to my bash execution and correct my mistake

```
for Eachfile in `find . -iname "*FOO*" ` 
do
cp $Eachfile MEOW
done
```

getting the following error

```
./baash.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''

'/baash.sh: line 2: `do
```

Comment: unique string in the filename or in the file contents?

Comment: unique string in the file content

Comment: this loop seems perfectly valid.It works  for me My wild guess is that you converted your script to Windows format (perhaps copying it from Windows) and then you receive this `error: unexpected do\r because the \r is unexpected` Use `dos2unix` to convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all files under the current directory with the string "FOO" in them and copy them to directory `MEOW`, use:

```
grep --null -lr FOO . | xargs -0 cp -t MEOW
```

Unlike `find`, `grep` looks in the contents of a file.  The `-l` option to `grep` tells it to list file names only.  The `-r` option tells it to look recursively in subdirectories.   Because file names can have spaces and other odd characters in them, we give the `--null` option to `grep` so that, in the list it produces, the file names are safely separated by null characters. `xargs -0` reads from that list of null-separated file names and provides them as argument to the command `cp -t MEOW` which copies them to the target directory `MEOW`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want to search for the string FOO in  .c and .h file then

```
find ./  -name "*\.c" -o -name "*\.h" -exec grep -l FOO {} \; | xargs  cp -t MEOW/
```

For me its working even without `--null` option to `xrags`, if doesn't for you.. then append `-0` in xargs part as follow:

```
xargs  -0 cp -t MEOW/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in $(find -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -exec grep -l 'FOO' {} \;); do
    dname=$(dirname "$file")
    dest="MEOW/$dname"
    mkdir -p $dest
    cp "$file" "$dest"
done
```